# theymeleaf inline javascript framework issue

Tags: javascript, inline, thymeleaf

```
<script th:inline="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //expose list data to javascript
    var listObject = /*[[${listObject}]]*/ [];
</script>
```

the replacement text printed into the file is different than what Jackson library's ObjectMapper does.

With Thymeleaf in above example, listObject will be

```
{
   "dataType":{
      "$type":"DataType",
      "$name":"STRING"
   },
   "friendlyName":"Customer Key"
}
```

If I print the object with ObjectMapper(which is also used with Spring @RequestBody/@ResponseBody), it will be

```
{
   "dataType":"STRING",
   "friendlyName":"Customer Key"
}
```

Is there a way I can force thymeleaf to be compatible with ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/81) has to say something about Jackson and JSON inlining in thymeleaf.
To summarize, the possibility to switch to custom TextInliners is considered for
3.0 thymeleaf milestone.

So, currently there is no "clean" way to switch to Jackson json serialization.

What you can do however, is sneak your own TextInliner. That is:

1. Create a class `org.thymeleaf.standard.inliner.StandardJavaScriptTextInliner`.
2. Implement your own version of `formatEvaluationResult(Object)` method,
   where you can call the Jackson ObjectMapper .
3. Put this new `StandardJavaScriptTextInliner` class in a proper place, so that it is loaded before the original class (f.e. in tomcat put it in classes dir under correct package structure).

Comment: This post is old so is this still the case? The issue in the link you provided is still not resolved. Also, why are there so few upvotes? This was the only SO answer on this I could find. My own issue is that Thymeleaf ignores my `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` so my inlined JSON contains alot of null values. Should I post a new SO question for this maybe?

Comment: The issue was fixed in thymeleaf 3.0.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

when you set listObject in the thymeleaf context, set it to the string that is obtained by converting listObject to a JSON string using Jackson

then use JS eval() or the better method - JSON.parse to convert the string into a JS object.