# Thymeleaf inline javascript ignore null

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf to inline my very large Java Object into my HTML as a JSON:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var myBigObject = /*[[${myBigJavaObject}]]*/ [];
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

This big Object contains a lot of null values which I don't want in my JSON since it increases the size by about 70% (~1MB).

For Spring MVC Jackson serialization I successfully use the following annotation on my model classes to automatically remove all null values in my web-service JSON responses:

`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`

However this annotation has no effect on Thymeleaf Javascript inline serialization.

How do I easily get rid of my null values with Thymeleaf Javascript inline serialization?

Side question: I feel this should be a major issue for a lot of people, yet the only SO issue I could find was this: [theymeleaf inline javascript framework issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318964/theymeleaf-inline-javascript-framework-issue) which is very old. Am I asking the wrong question or is it so rare for people to want to clean their inlined JS of null values when using Thymeleaf?

Comment: This issue at Thymeleaf addresses this issue: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/81

Comment: I had the same feeling when I encountered this issue. I resorted to manually serializing my big object then render the output json string to the template.