# Is there any way to add an ExclusionStrategy to Thymeleaf 3.0.5?

Tags: java, jackson, thymeleaf

Now that Thyemleaf 3.0.5 is using Jackson, is there any way to add something like com.google.gson.ExclusionStrategy into the mix?

Also related to this:

[Thymeleaf inline javascript ignore null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821081/thymeleaf-inline-javascript-ignore-null)

**UPDATE:**

Using the answer suggested by Metroids I was able to get this to work.
I first had to switch from my XML config file to using a java config file for configuring Thymeleaf.  Then I was able to get access to the StandardDialect as shown by Metroids.  I implemented IStandardJavaScriptSerializer interface overriding #serializeValue(Object object, Writer writer).

IStandardJavaScriptSerializer implementation snippet...

```
@Override
public void serializeValue(Object object, Writer writer) {
    try {
        ExclusionStrategy exclusionStrategy = new MyApiJsonExcludeExclusionStrategy();
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setExclusionStrategies(exclusionStrategy);
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    writer.write(gson.toJson(object));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new TemplateProcessingException("An exception was raised while trying to serialize object to JavaScript using Gson", e);
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf Java Config snippet...

```
@Bean
public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

    Set<IDialect> dialects = engine.getDialects();
    StandardDialect dialect = (StandardDialect) dialects.stream()
            .filter(d -> d instanceof StandardDialect)
            .findFirst()
            .get();
    dialect.setJavaScriptSerializer(new MyThymeleafJavascriptSerializer());

    engine.setTemplateResolvers(getTemplateResolvers());
    engine.setAdditionalDialects(getAdditionalDialects());
    return engine;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible... but it's still kind of ugly to do in my opinion (since there is no easy way to get to the ObjectMapper without creating one yourself).  I accomplished it by doing this...  First, wherever you configure your template engine, you should be able to get access to the StandardDialect.

```
    Set<IDialect> dialects = templateEngine.getDialects();
    StandardDialect dialect = (StandardDialect) dialects.stream()
            .filter(d -> d instanceof StandardDialect)
            .findFirst()
            .get();
```

From there you can create your own `IStandardJavaScriptSerializer` in which you can configure the ObjectMapper however you desire. (I created a `SpecialJacksonSerializer` with this line of code `this.mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);` to verify it worked.)

```
dialect.setJavaScriptSerializer(new SpecialJacksonSerializer());
```

Since thymeleaf is doing a lot of configuration in the background (see [this file](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3.0-master/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/standard/serializer/StandardJavaScriptSerializer.java)), you end up copying a lot of that code when creating your own.  It would be nice if you could call `dialect.getJavaScriptSerializer().getObjectMapper()` or something like that, but it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: Thank you!  This was 95% of what I needed.  I had to switch over from using XML config to use a java config and then I was able to do basically what you have here.  I ended up building my own IStandardJavaScriptSerializer see the code in my update to the question.
Thanks again, really appreciate your help.